# How to create 2 spark masters/workers on same machine?

Tags: apache-spark

By defining different ports I was hoping to launch 2 masters on the same machine, but it failed miserably:

```
$ $SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-master.sh --port 8001 --webui-port 8011
starting org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master, logging to /Users/brandl/bin/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-brandl-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-scicomp-mac-12.local.out
$ $SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-master.sh --port 8002 --webui-port 8012
org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master running as process 29436.  Stop it first.
```

Why isn't that working? Do I need to adjust more settings to allow for multiple instances?

Following the same logic I may want to start two workers on the same machine. But even if they are supposed to be connected to different masters this fails as well with  similar error:

```
$SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-slave.sh --webui-port 8050 spark://foo:7077
starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /Users/brandl/bin/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-brandl-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-scicomp-mac-12.local.out
starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to /Users/brandl/bin/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark-brandlorg.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-2-scicomp-mac-12.local.out
$SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-slave.sh --webui-port 8051 spark://bar:7077
org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker running as process 29503.  Stop it first.
org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker running as process 29526.  Stop it first.
```

If checked the [spark standalone docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0-preview/spark-standalone.html) but could not find any guidance about what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 7):

Since there was no answer in here, I went back to the spark sources, and searched for the [code bits](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ef1622899ffc6ab136102ffc6bcc714402e6f334/sbin/spark-daemon.sh#L163) where the error was thrown. This revelaled that by setting a different `SPARK_IDENT_STRING` multiple masters and workers can run on the same machine

```
$ $SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-master.sh --port 8001 --webui-port 8011
export SPARK_IDENT_STRING=foo
$ $SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-master.sh --port 8002 --webui-port 8012
```

The default value is the username (`$USER`)