# Starting multiple workers on a master node in Standalone mode

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-standalone

I have a machine with 80 cores. I'd like to start a Spark server in standalone mode on this machine with 8 executors, each with 10 cores. But, when I try to start my second worker on the master, I get an error.

```
$ ./sbin/start-master.sh
Starting org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master, logging to ...
$ ./sbin/start-slave.sh spark://localhost:7077 -c 10
Starting org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker, logging to ...
$ ./sbin/start-slave.sh spark://localhost:7077 -c 10
org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker running as process 64606.  Stop it first.
```

In the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#starting-a-cluster-manually), it clearly states "you can start one or more workers and connect them to the master via: `./sbin/start-slave.sh <master-spark-URL>`". So why can't I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way to get the same parallelism is to start many workers.

You can do this by adding to the ./conf/spark-env.sh file:

```
SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=8
SPARK_WORKER_CORES=10
SPARK_EXECUTOR_CORES=10
```

Answer (score 1):

In a single machine, it is quite complicated but you can try docker or Kubernetes. 
Create multiple docker containers for spark workers.

Comment: That's kind of what I thought. It just can't be done with a single machine. The documentation just needs to be clearer :)

Answer (score 1):

Just specify a new identity for every new worker/master and then launch the `start-worker.sh`

```sh
 export SPARK_IDENT_STRING=worker2
  ./spark-node2/sbin/start-worker.sh spark://DESKTOP-HSK5ETQ.localdomain:7077
```

thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/46205968/1743724